# Is this the best way to call multiple functions with onclick in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, onclick, format

---

Is this an acceptable/helpful way to use multiple functions with onclick? I know it works, but I just want to format correctly.

---

```
<button type="button" onclick="validateForm()">Submit</button>
<script>
function validateForm () {
    let x = document.forms["myForm"]["myInput"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        document.getElementById("noName").innerHTML = "Please Enter Name";
        return false;
    } else {
        getInputValue(), getHoliday(), hello();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It depends on your groups coding standards

Comment: most people would use `;` instead of `,` between those functions, but in this case there's not any difference

Comment: I would have a line break after every function call, also end with `;`

Comment: @Bravo The OP shouldn't be using the comma operator unless they know what it does, which I doubt, but once they understand it, they'd realize it was inappropriate here

Comment: @Dexygen - but in this case there's not any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you want to use semicolons `;` and *line breaks*.

It offers more readability and quick changes like the deletion of a line. With the appropriate line breaks and statements, you would not even need semicolons either with JS's [ASI](https://blog.alexdevero.com/automatic-semicolon-insertion-in-javascript/).

If you want to add even more functions, you could consider delegating the task to a function handler like this to separate your concerns:

```
function getFormValues() {
  getInputValue();
  getHoliday();
  hello();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is acceptable, but use ; instead of ,